# Replace a list of tuples based on condition

Tags: list, tuples

My program has two lists
List 1 [(x-coordinate,y-coordinate,List1_id)] (list of tuples)
List 2 [(x-coordinate,y-coordinate,List2_id)] (list of tuples)

So, now I have a code that runs to compute the distance between all the points in List 1 and List 2. So, my resulting list is
ResultList = [(List1_id, List2_id, distance)]

Since the dataset is too big, my ResultList is about 4gb long. I don't need all the distances. I need only minimum distance of a given combination of list ids

So, my resulting list should be 
[(List1_id1, List2_id1, min_distance),(List1_id1, List1_id2, min_distance),(List1_id2, List2_id1, min_distance) and so on..]

from

[(List1_id1, List2_id1, distance),(List1_id1, List1_id2, distance),(List1_id2, List2_id1, distance), (List1_id1, List2_id1, distance), (List1_id1, List2_id1, distance), (List1_id1, List1_id2, distance) and so on..]

I hope this makes sense :|

So, currently, I calculate the distance and append to a new list. I need to apply a logic that when I append to the list, the new element must be added only if the distance is minimum for any combination of list IDs. This will make sure that my list is not GBs long

Edit 2 - Some data
List 1 - [(99363.044,441277.027,8),(99373.343,441272.8,8),(99354.918,441288.428,8),(99362.324,441291.766,8),(99360.426,441264.083,8),(99369.039,441287.165,5),(99364.127,441288.681,5)]

List 2 - [(99360.05,441264.68,42,0),(99360.05,441264.69,42,0),(99360.05,441264.7,42,0),(99360.15,441264.58,42,0),(99360.15,441264.62,42,0),(99361.26,441279.93,53,0),(99361.26,441280.14,53,0),(99361.26,441279.9,53,0),(99361.26,441279.81,53,0),(99354.55,441271.69,63,0),(99354.55,441275.66,63,0),(99354.55,441271.66,63,0),(99354.55,441275.64,63,0),(99354.55,441275.48,63,0),(99354.55,441270.59,63,0),(99354.55,441275.44,63,0),(99354.55,441271.06,63,0),(99354.55,441272.84,63,0),(99355.32,441273.42,63,0),(99355.32,441275.26,63,0),(99355.32,441274.48,63,0),(99355.32,441274.95,63,0),(99358.02,441284.35,68,0),(99358.02,441284.36,68,0),(99358.02,441284.4,68,0),(99358.02,441284.49,68,0),(99358.02,441283.97,68,0),(99358.16,441284.34,68,0),(99358.16,441284.36,68,0),(99358.16,441284,68,0)]

Obtained result
[(42, 5, 24.334954489354597), (42, 5, 24.387460917433867), (63, 5, 16.052616297632952), (42, 8, 12.74005043161773), (42, 8, 24.286417356220991), (42, 8, 0.56849362356923416), (42, 8, 24.276643260552106), (63, 8, 9.5884464330723027), (53, 8, 16.078644376965897), (42, 5, 24.196659810778854), (68, 5, 7.3672335377565004), (63, 8, 8.6337271789140431), (68, 8, 8.5137754257193521), (63, 5, 17.619914017943259), (42, 5, 24.27131117180317), (42, 5, 24.426926331373604), (63, 5, 22.01503454456742), (63, 8, 12.79329386827386), (68, 8, 8.8889518504529388), (53, 8, 14.029817853416182), (63, 8, 18.977524838601038), (53, 8, 10.700041495254004), (63, 8, 10.641936149028002), (68, 8, 20.383346266049983), (63, 8, 12.965015426166449), (42, 8, 12.695101614399849), (68, 5, 11.239807204741309), (68, 8, 8.5700539671281586), (63, 8, 10.047523326678597), (53, 8, 11.913607849829605), (53, 8, 3.5879555460002752), (42, 8, 27.161359170695093), (63, 8, 18.21630785860641), (68, 8, 20.40322241706173), (68, 5, 11.339046961713443), (53, 8, 3.4073545456772449), (63, 8, 21.556583959454493), (42, 8, 27.232913762585632), (63, 5, 18.684758119918691), (53, 8, 15.86893080835191), (63, 8, 17.930534069001059), (42, 5, 24.234094701462343), (42, 5, 24.344813205268306), (42, 8, 0.72254065632100728), (42, 8, 0.71402030785190995), (63, 8, 18.08240448612629), (63, 8, 17.902037649371213), (68, 8, 5.4310374699841022), (68, 8, 5.0840129818797895), (53, 8, 13.969215761813532), (63, 8, 8.6032973329956892), (68, 8, 8.8105814223397942), (68, 8, 8.4536732844420808), (63, 8, 18.827544954127116), (53, 8, 14.014595570349684), (68, 8, 20.45896686056269), (63, 5, 16.710225911093556), (63, 8, 18.0336609982418), (68, 8, 8.9051688361531518), (68, 8, 19.194476523198581), (63, 8, 9.1217270842880183), (42, 8, 15.571639252163617), (63, 5, 18.613713922803964), (63, 8, 19.637508294091823), (63, 5, 18.513690771945917), (68, 5, 11.360615564297584), (53, 8, 10.62768780119729), (42, 5, 24.215229629293152), (68, 8, 8.8807040824213157), (68, 8, 5.1237181811943104), (53, 5, 10.623467701270917), (63, 8, 18.922498487236851), (42, 8, 27.181289005499924), (53, 5, 9.3227855279266194), (68, 8, 8.8119039940279258), (68, 5, 7.7129093084233054), (68, 8, 20.045489392894488), (53, 8, 10.436086814504577), (63, 8, 15.592343249160891), (53, 5, 9.2086747146265946), (68, 8, 20.419244966454769), (63, 8, 10.657532782006815), (53, 8, 3.3818316043413272), (42, 8, 12.779007981828714), (53, 8, 11.883728034595848), (53, 8, 11.67458658795881), (68, 8, 8.5744662807839234), (63, 5, 20.055387555449311), (63, 8, 10.031530541240986), (68, 8, 5.1157626997569583), (63, 8, 22.557882258733933), (63, 5, 20.374904809561844), (68, 5, 11.234797105421109), (63, 5, 16.309056686388619), (68, 8, 19.082900434672979), (42, 8, 27.171324075208528), (63, 5, 18.50124714715599), (53, 5, 9.237188425017159), (63, 8, 12.95322847790688), (63, 5, 16.31268248936852), (63, 5, 18.368919020974811), (63, 8, 17.371898226750695), (68, 8, 19.0707915147892), (42, 8, 24.296191635748073), (63, 8, 18.983130642747213), (53, 5, 10.481577457599492), (68, 5, 11.472854309196546), (42, 8, 15.523132705735247), (68, 8, 8.9964962624199476), (63, 5, 16.341450669976716), (68, 5, 7.4580433090399447), (68, 8, 19.273049291685261), (68, 8, 20.409314662665938), (63, 8, 9.4698999466550209), (63, 8, 15.01338296324063), (63, 8, 8.6064978359273443), (63, 8, 12.982846567676086), (68, 8, 8.9219787603546088), (63, 5, 18.164250218470507), (42, 8, 12.685383912192332), (63, 5, 20.46956789964668), (68, 8, 20.548345067189207), (68, 5, 7.4067489494241725), (63, 8, 8.5247067398202496), (63, 5, 19.504179295708195), (42, 8, 15.544248100166255), (68, 8, 5.4879639211748898), (53, 8, 12.003250892992714), (68, 8, 8.5132946031419188), (68, 8, 8.5658188166784157), (68, 8, 5.2018446728271828), (42, 8, 15.576849777784778), (42, 8, 24.376108959405205), (42, 8, 0.60377562059008572), (63, 8, 22.117267281472209), (63, 8, 11.583127600088826), (68, 8, 8.4963363869476058), (53, 8, 15.749097910686972), (68, 5, 11.370417142742211), (63, 8, 8.640984029603004), (68, 8, 5.2175001676950679), (63, 5, 21.221124993745853), (63, 8, 7.9235386665163343), (42, 8, 27.272786289620047), (63, 8, 13.953791886111953), (63, 8, 18.19011074731587), (63, 8, 17.884023932012049), (63, 8, 20.46041426753143), (63, 8, 18.101130600034072), (68, 5, 7.3789816370214911), (63, 8, 10.545730178644387), (63, 8, 18.793042568984102), (68, 5, 11.372888199574382), (63, 8, 12.288065958504605), (63, 5, 21.663382607511704), (63, 8, 21.52860543555683), (68, 5, 11.330042630100078), (63, 8, 10.380420270870811), (68, 8, 19.188455617881456), (63, 8, 17.841795537434088), (42, 8, 12.704819754729604), (63, 8, 12.773302157274143), (63, 8, 16.742044916927171), (63, 8, 13.174134810306763), (63, 5, 19.530319249824927), (63, 8, 12.787056932713549), (68, 8, 20.032014501780179), (53, 8, 10.603629944515824), (53, 5, 10.705553045026424), (42, 8, 24.41517822994124), (53, 8, 3.3057139924644763), (63, 8, 8.7674640005297135), (42, 5, 24.325095888783526), (63, 8, 18.825752282435211), (68, 8, 18.866994699738399), (63, 8, 18.873379374124106), (63, 5, 18.638850447371869), (42, 5, 24.205944435179109), (42, 8, 15.566433406511978), (68, 5, 7.5839864187451367), (63, 8, 19.006379165948232), (68, 8, 5.0130078795250803), (63, 8, 18.651053911255637), (63, 8, 8.1331042658944277), (68, 8, 8.793942517452491), (63, 8, 16.77203768184846), (53, 5, 10.643921551735795), (42, 8, 0.70553880121043167), (63, 8, 18.046298013735743), (53, 5, 9.0093490330572585), (63, 8, 9.6121706705780792), (68, 5, 7.4810754574348568), (63, 5, 19.419989340877574), (68, 8, 18.96215254129423), (63, 8, 12.993212381867547), (63, 8, 12.82259665590326), (63, 5, 16.163705330153071), (63, 5, 16.179821074381103), (68, 5, 7.4868558153549847), (63, 8, 7.9983813987434456), (68, 8, 8.5312585237825154), (53, 8, 14.13769744337263), (63, 8, 12.006786622597852), (63, 5, 18.510975392951089), (68, 8, 19.218593314821081), (53, 8, 15.838972346753351), (63, 8, 18.150785905839268), (63, 5, 21.19921569302317), (63, 8, 19.009377922477256), (63, 8, 13.483993770395951)]

Expected result
[(42, 5, 24.334954489354597),(63, 5, 16.052616297632952), (42, 8, 12.74005043161773),(63, 8, 9.5884464330723027), (53, 8, 16.078644376965897),(68, 8, 8.5137754257193521),(53, 5, 10.623467701270917),(68, 5, 7.3672335377565004)]

Of course in the expected result, the values don't reflect the true minimum but they should be from the obtained result. I hope you get what I mean

Comment: Why not just iterate over the list to determine which index has the least distance, then replace it?

Comment: I tried that. So, my new code looks like this 

a=[(22420, 1, 2.0), (22420, 1, 329.97700353481213),(22420, 1, 0.0)]
element = a[-1]
for d1,d2 in enumerate(a):
    if (element[0]==a[d1][0] and element[1]==a[d1][1] and element[2]<a[d1][2]):
        a[d1] = element
    a.pop()

print(a)

But there is still something wrong. Doesn't really work the way I want

Comment: Can you elaborate more, what were you expecting the code to do and what did not really work the way you want?

Comment: Also, I found your explanation about needing only the least distance contradictive with your example. If you need the least distance, you will eliminate the maximum distance and replace it with the new element. So the new element should replace the `a[1]`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! Got the code running to give me what I want!

```
expected_list = []

for b1, b2 in enumerate(list1):
    for l1, l2 in enumerate(list2):
        replace = None
        bp1 = list1[b1][0]
        bp2 = list1[b1][1]
        lp1 = list2[l1][0]
        lp2 = list2[l1][1]
        d = numpy.sqrt((bp1 - lp1) * (bp1 - lp1) + (bp2 - lp2) * (bp2 - lp2))
        if(len(expected_list) == 0 ):
            expected_list.append((int(list2[l1][2]), int(list1[b1][2]), d))
        else:
            for d1, d2 in enumerate(expected_list):
                if (expected_list[d1][0] == int(list2[l1][2]) and expected_list[d1][1] == int(list1[b1][2])):
                    min_distance = min(expected_list[d1][2],d)
                    replace = d1

            if (replace == None):
                expected_list.append((int(list2[l1][2]), int(list1[b1][2]), d))
            else:
                expected_list[replace] = (int(list2[l1][2]), int(list1[b1][2]), min_distance)

print(expected_list)
```

If anybody can help me optimize the code, I will be grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
obtained_result = [(42, 5, 24.334954489354597),
                   (42, 5, 24.387460917433867),
                   (63, 5, 16.052616297632952),
                    #...
                  ]

from itertools import groupby
expected_result = [(k[0], k[1], min([x[2] for x in v]))
              for k, v in groupby(sorted(obtained_result), lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))]
```

The list comprehension first sort `obtained_result` so it can then be grouped by `groupby` using `(x[0], x[1])` as the key. We then find the minimum of the elements in the same group, and assign it to create new list of tuples.

This gave us:

```
>>> expected_result
[(42, 5, 24.196659810778854),
 (42, 8, 0.5684936235692342),
 (53, 5, 9.009349033057259),
 (53, 8, 3.3057139924644763),
 (63, 5, 16.05261629763295),
 (63, 8, 7.923538666516334),
 (68, 5, 7.3672335377565),
 (68, 8, 5.01300787952508)]
```

Is it what you want? Anyhow, I think `dict` would be a better choice for your data.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) See, the thing is the distance element is tied to the first two elements. I will edit my question to explain better

Comment: It would be helpful if you could write out the example inputs and outputs you are expecting.

Comment: Hi, I have posted that in the question

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Again! Thank you so much for helping me! :) I do not want to get the expected result from the obtained result. The problem is I can't store obtained result because it runs into several GBs. So, I want to get the expected result directly from lists 1 and 2. So, I don't mind if the expected result is in the form of a multi key dictionary. I will also try it out! Again, thank you very very much! :)